# Xcode build not showing Table Cell

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard

In the interface builder I see:
[image]

but in the built running app, I don't see my red text cell:
[image]

here's my `Main.storyboard` TableView in the Interface Build side panel:
[image]

it's just a normal table view dragged out from the UI Objects menu onto the Storyboard.

Comment: Show your code and related info regarding what you've done to show the row.

Comment: @Frankenstein, I have no IBOutlets or IBActions using this table yet, I just dragged it into the storyboard. Does it need init code in the ViewController?

Comment: From what you are saying I think the cell in IB is just the template cell - you need to tell the tableview how to use the template cell throught he tableview delegate/datasource methods.  So yes, you'll need to write the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be missing the configuration required in `NSTableViewDataSource` and `NSTableViewDelegate` methods as follows. You need to set the `dataSource` and `delegate` of the `NSTableView` you just drag and dropped and implement `numberOfRowsInTableView` method for the class that conforms to these protocols.

```
func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Note: It would be best if you go through [this](https://www.appcoda.com/macos-programming-tableview/) tutorial which I found helpful for Cocoa development with `NSTableView`.